# Updating Inventory Stock After Check Out in Cart Activity Using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a point of sales project using Firebase Realtime Db. As the picture attached each user has children's "product" and "cart". What I want to ask is how to update the value of "stock" in the inventory when doing the check out the method in the cart activity.

[image: My db screenshot for example]

I found this method but I know it will not working. It will destroy another node and child instead update it. But later I found `updateChildren()` method but I didnt have any idea to use that into my project.

```
private void checkOut() { //when I press the check out button
    String userId = "user1"; //as shown at the db screenshot

    DatabaseReference inventoryRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("users").child(userId).child("product");
    DatabaseReference cartRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("users").child(userId).child("shopingCart");

    cartRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            inventoryRef.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError firebaseError, DatabaseReference firebase) {
                    if (firebaseError != null) {
                        System.out.println("Copy failed");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Success");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It sounds like a pretty clear use-case, but I'm not sure where you are having problems. Can you edit your question to show what you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the value of the `stock` property when you know the user and the product ID, you can do that with:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("users")
    .child("user1")
    .child("product")
    .child("product-0001")
    .child("stock")
    .setValue(42);
```

The same result can be accomplished with this shorter code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("users/user1/product/product-0001/stock")
    .setValue(42);
```

Or with this use of `updateChildren` to only update one or a few of the properties:

```
Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("stock", 42);

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("users/user1/product/product-0001")
    .updateChildren(values);
```

---

If you want to increment/decrement the stock based on its current value, you can either [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) or use the [atomic increment/decrement operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("users/user1/product/product-0001/stock")
    .setValue(ServerValue.increment(-20));
```

---

Finally, not that your data structure is not in line with the recommendations in the Firebase documentation on [keeping your data structure flat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#flatten_data_structures). I'd recommend changing it to two top-level lists (say `userProducts` and `userCarts`) and then the same UID-based child nodes under it.

---

**Update**: If you want to update the stock of multiple products in one go, you can use `updateChildren` to perform a multi-path update like this:

```
Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("product/product-0001/stock", 42);
values.put("product/product-0002/stock", 21);

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/user1")
    .updateChildren(values);
```

Comment: But in my case we dont know how much product inside the cart before we call the checkOut method. I mean when in the cart has only one idProduct, so it should update stock at only one  idProduct. Same when in the cart has two idProduct, so it should update stock at those two.

I got myself confused when trying to get idProduct string from every child in the cart. And no idea how to update every idProduct inventory stock that I dont know how much product inside the cart.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, which is why I tried to cover all cases in my answer. Did you try any of the code I gave in my answer?

Comment: I've tried all of them before but it can only update stock value for one product only. Not all product inside the cart. What I want is in one method checkOut() I can get every quantity value from the product inside cart and update specific product stock in user inventory. My idea is move cartRef into productRef (inventory) and I hope it will update the inventory stock magically with something code I dont know.

Comment: I added an example of updating the `stock` property for multiple products in one call to my answer too.

Comment: Thank you its new for me. But in your example is updating stock for 2 (two) products. And the number of product inside userCart is not always 2 (two). And what I want to get from userCart are number of product and each idProduct. Then when I have those data how to use it into your example method.

Comment: Thank you, I am new on this forum and than information is very useful for me. But its say Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. I will update my question to increase chance to get accepted answer...

Comment: Did you *try* using what I showed already, to make your use-case?

Comment: Yes of course I use your example method for editing specific product detail. And will use your another example method "update the stock of multiple products in one go" when I know how to get all idProduct and quantity from cart first. And now I almost solved my case. Its about the position of my cartList. Start from 0 to last position in my cartList. When I get all data per product on cart, then I just call your "update the stock of multiple products in one go" method. Can you help me to get all value from my cartList? It would be very helpfull...

Answer (score 0):

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("cart_item").child(mobileNo).child(orderId);
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists())

            for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){

                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("products")
                                .child(mobileNo);
                databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot dss: snapshot.getChildren()){

                            int itemStock = (Integer.parseInt(dss.child("stock").getValue().toString())) -Integer.parseInt(ds.child("itemQuantity").getValue().toString());
                                    String s_stock = String.valueOf(itemStock);

                            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("products").child(mobileNo).child(ds.child("itemCode").getValue().toString());
                            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("stock",s_stock);
                            databaseReference.updateChildren(map);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });


            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```